# Cast object to it's parent type with generics

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, casting, abstract

I'm trying to cast an object to it's parent type which the object has derived from.

So, I've got this ViewModel

```
public abstract class CostsChargesViewModel<T> where T : CostsChargesBasePage
```

And I have a FundCostPageViewModel which derives from it:

```
public class FundCostPageViewModel : CostsChargesViewModel<FundCostPage>
```

Respectively, I've got the FundCostPage, which inherits from the CostsChargesBasePage

```
public class FundCostPage : CostsChargesBasePage
```

So - within the context of having an instance of the FundCostPageViewModel, I want to be able to cast it to a `CostChargesViewModel<CostsChargesBasePage>`.

For example, imagine it's a Razor view setup like this:

```
@model TSC.Website.Core.ViewModel.Pages.FundCostPageViewModel

var foo = Model as CostsChargesViewModel<FundCostPage>; // This would work

var bar = Model as CostsChargesViewModel<CostsChargesBasePage>; // Won't work
```

How can I cast the parent class of the FundCostPage into the CostsChargesViewModel?

It's kind of like a double cast - essentially a way to do this:

```
Model as CostsChargesViewModel<FundCostPage as CostChargesBasePage>
```

Comment: it is related to covariance and classes does not support covariance in c#

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've seen this done in the past

Comment: You can't cast `IEnumerable<int>` to `IEnumerable<Object>`, but you can call `Cast<object>()` on an `IEnumerable<int>`. Depending on what you need from `bar`, you may be able to give your class a method along those lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The classes does not support [co-variance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/) at least currently in C# and dont' see any near future that happening. What you can do is introduce an interface like:

```
public interface ICostsChargesViewModel<out T> where T : CostsChargesBasePage
```

and your abstract class would be implementing it:

```
public abstract class CostsChargesViewModel<T> : ICostsChargesViewModel<T>  
                                       where T : CostsChargesBasePage
```

and then you would be able to write like following and would work ofcourse :

```
var bar = Model as ICostsChargesViewModel<CostsChargesBasePage>;
```

[See this DEMO Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4AJtqz)